# Figuring out the efficient way of expressing Taylor polynomial of $f(x) = e^{e^{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

In a question from *Spivak's Calculus 2nd ed* - pg 427, I'm asked to find the Taylor polynomial of $f(x) = e^{e^{x}}$ of degree 3, at 0.

I do know how to do this the long way. It would simply be calculating the coefficients of the Taylor Polynomial individually where the coefficients are expressed as:

$$a_{k} = \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}$$

For a function as the one given this becomes extremely tedious and I was trying to be clever about my expression so I attempted the following:

Let $y = e^{x}$. Therefore $f(y) = e^{y}$. We know that the Taylor polynomial of 3rd degree for $e^{y}$ is:

$$e^{y} \approx 1 + \frac{y}{1!} + \frac{y^{2}}{2!} + \frac{y^{3}}{3!}$$

Using this then I could express $f(x) = e^{e^{x}}$ as:

$$P_{3,0,f} = 1 + \frac{e^{x}}{1!} + \frac{e^{2x}}{2!} + \frac{e^{3x}}{3!}$$

This is what I thought I could do, but after looking at the answer the correct solution is supposed to be:

$$P_{3,0,f} = e + ex + ex^{2} + \frac{5e}{3!}x^{3}$$

I could obtain this by doing the rote calculations, but I have the feeling that the purpose of this exercise is to get me to avoid having to go through such a tedious process. So my question is how to reconcile what my attempt was trying to accomplish with what the final result is?

Comment: For the general term see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: Just out of curiosity @AnginaSeng could the expression that I wrote actually work? Of course I would still end up having to use some Taylor expansions to write out the individual $e^{x}$ terms, but I don't see anything inherently wrong with the expression beyond not satisfying what the question in the text was asking for specifically.

Comment: To get each coefficient, you need all terms in that sum, not just the first four.

Comment: @AnginaSeng so to make sure I understand clearly what you mean, I would need to have something of the form: $P_{3,0,f} = 1 + \frac{e^{x}}{1!} + \frac{e^{2x}}{2!} + \frac{e^{3x}}{3!} + \dots + \frac{e^{nx}}{n!}$ and collect all the necessary terms once I expand each of the inner Taylor polynomials. Would that be valid?

Comment: You need to take the infinite sum.

Comment: Yes, you're right...I should've put some more dots at the end because that is what I wanted to express. But being an infinite sum I guess there wouldn't be a closed form to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+\cdots$$
\begin{align}
e^{e^x}&=e\,e^x e^{x^2/2}e^{x^3/6}\cdots\\
&=e\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+\cdots\right)
\left(1+\frac{x^2}2+\cdots\right)
\left(1+\frac{x^3}6+\cdots\right)\cdots\\
&=e\left(1+x+x^2+\frac{5x^3}{6}+\cdots\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Nice....thanks for the assistance once again.